# What is the general term of this sequence of integers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, real-numbers

Consider the following sequence:

0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4 ...

What is the general term of this sequence? Also, can its general term be expressed without using any other functions, such as floor or ceil functions (that is, can it be expressed purely with arithmetic operators)?

Thanks for any help.

Edit: My progress was that I had gotten as far as getting the $(-1)^n$ part, but that was easy. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Hint: use the fact that $(-1)^n = 1$ if $n$ is even and $-1$ if $n$ is odd.

Comment: Can we create a new AP, $$ 0,±1,±2±3\cdots $$ Let the $ m^{th} $ term of this AP be, $m = \left[\frac{n+1}{2}\right]$ where [.] is the greatest integer function. When $n$ is odd then the term is negative and when $n$ is even then the term is positive(Here, $n$ is the position of term in the AP $ {0,+1,-1,+2,-2 \cdots}$ ) Does it make sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is $(-1)^n $ times $$0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,\ldots.$$ 
If we subtraxt $\frac n2$ from the latter, we arrive at $$-\frac12,0,-\frac12,0,-\frac12,0,\ldots$$
Add $\frac 14$ to make it symmetric:
$$ -\frac14,\frac14,-\frac14,\frac14,-\frac14,\frac14,\ldots$$
and recognize this as $\frac14(-1)^n$. 
Wrapping things up, the original sequence is 
$$ (-1)^n\left(\frac{(-1)^n-1}4+\frac n2\right)$$
or, slightly simplified
$$ \frac{1+(-1)^n(2n-1)}4.$$

Answer (score 2):

How about 
$$(-1)^{n+1}\left \lfloor \frac {n+1}2\right \rfloor$$

Comment: OP asked not to use floor function

Comment: Oops doh. I'm on the beach, can't really read my screen in the sun. Not a joke or bad excuse. 